Cannot copy to a folder after opening it using a hyperlink in OneNote
This is a bit of a weird issue that I haven't been able to find any information on. I use one note to manage some file locations to some network drives. For some reason I have started having an issue where I cannot copy to a folder that I opened using the hyperlink. I can copy files to the same folder just fine if I navigate to it through file explorer normally, it is just when I open the folder with a onenote hyperlink that something breaks. It seems to be onenote specific, as hyperlinks in excel do not share this issue. Any help would be appreciated!


It probably depends on how onenote is creating links. There's a few formats depending on how the folder is set up. You could try using some of the other formats to narrow down which ones are not working.

P:\folder 
\\server\folder
file://\\folder

The file:// links would be the most likely candidate as once onenote opens it, it can lock the file access - even if it's a folder. It can also take a while to release this lock. I suspect if you terminate the onenote process you will be able to access the folder - if not then it's not onenote.
The solution I propose is to manually set the links in onenote to use the first or second format and see if the problem disappears or changes.
Also check if the folder is a network mapped drive, symlink or a junction.

Thank you for your help this helped me figure it out! file:///\(server url) ended up working for me, referring to it as just the P drive was the problem.
